# How to set border to pdf in fpdf?

Tags: php, fpdf

I have created 1 PDF using `fpdf` and I want to set border to each page in that PDF. So is there any built-in tag for setting a border on a PDF in `fpdf` or any other easy way to do this? I don't want to change the layout of my PDF after setting the border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well thanks for that. But I think finally I found a solution for that. If you set a `rectangle` in a `header function`, it will work as a border to all pages.

Answer (score 3):

```
$this->Rect(5, 5, 200, 287, 'D'); //For A4
```

Comment: Can you explain how this code works? It is a very low quality answer in this form.

Answer (score 2):

by default (A4) the page width is 210, page height is 297.You can probably make a box on every page by overriding the header

```
$pageWidth = 210;
$pageHeight = 297;

function Header()
{
  $margin = 10;
  $this->Rect( $margin, $margin , $pageWidth - $margin , $pageHeight - margin);
}
```

Comment: For width and height you must subtract the margin twice, else you will not have a margin right and bottom. I updated your answer.

Comment: You missed the $ sign from margin, it should be $margin.
$this->Rect( $margin, $margin , $pageWidth - $margin , $pageHeight - $margin);

Comment: And as Timo002 metioned you must subtract the margin twice 

$this->Rect($margin, $margin , $pageWidth - $margin * 2 , $pageHeight - $margin * 2);

Answer (score 0):

By default i dont know of any help that creates a border in FPDF Complete Page, you have to create a cell that some how covers whole page and shows it self as a border you can try some thing like this

Try this link http://fpdf.de/funktionsreferenz/?funktion=Cell

```
   border (optional)        mixed       Specifies whether around the cell, a frame is to be drawn. The value can be a number:
0: without frame
1: with frame
or a string consisting of one or more of the following characters (The order is not to be considered):
L: left frame
T: Frame Up
R: right frame
B: frame below
By default, no border is drawn (value 0).
```

Answer (score 0):

$pdf->Rect(5, 5, 200, 287, 'S');

Comment: How is that different or better than https://stackoverflow.com/a/33580098/2227743 ?

Answer (score 0):

From documentation:
http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script32.php

Changes in parameters:

> border: indicates if borders must be drawn around the cell. The value can be either a number:
> 0: no border
>
> > 0: frame of the corresponding width